# What happens if I use c++ 17 features in my ros nodes?

Tags: c++, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the ROS manual/wiki you can see, that ROS is only made for C++11. But what exactly does that mean? What happens if I just put `add_compile_options(-std=c++17)` in the CMakeLists.txt of my ROS-package and use C++17-features anyway? Specifically: Is it possible to use parallel `std::for_each` from C++17 in my ROS-nodes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341313/what-happens-if-i-use-c++-17-features-in-my-ros-nodes?/) by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2020-01-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-09**:\

> In the ROS manual/wiki you can see

please always link to pages you are referring to. Right now we don't know what you "see" exactly.

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2020-01-09**:
@gvdhoorn I know, sorry. The thing was just, that I couldn't actually find where exactly I had read that, but I rather just had it in the back of my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ROS is only made for C++11

this is actually not really true.

For ROS 1: Melodic has lifted the max version to C++14 (see [here](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#c)).

For ROS 2: all ROS 2 versions target C++14 by default (see [REP-2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html), search for "Minimum language requirements").

> What happens if I just put `add_compile_options(-std=c++17)` in the CMakeLists.txt of my ROS-package and use C++17-features anyway?

Nothing. It probably will just work, as long as your C++17 object code is ABI compatible with whatever libraries you are linking against.

In other words: you'll potentially run into the exact same problems you could have with ABI incompatibilities between libraries when not using ROS.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2020-01-09**:
Thanks for your answer. But how can I find out, if the object code is ABI compatible after all? Will I get errors if the compatibility is not given, or can it happen that there will be just arbitrary, undefined behaviour occurring?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-09**:
Yes, could be linking errors, could also be `SEGFAULT`s. I can't give you a more definitive answer unfortunately.

As I wrote: there is nothing really ROS specific here. It's essentially plain C++.

From my own personal experience though: C++03 + C++11 was troublesome (`std::string` etc). C++11 and newer has not been a problem for me so far (ie: combining binary artefacts compiled with these different versions). But again: personal experience, so this is not a guarantee everything will work.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2020-01-09**:
In addition to above-mentioned, you can also use the `set_properties` macro in `CMakeLists` to set cpp standards for specific targets only (where you know you need c++17 for example) within a package instead for the whole package as it is done with `add_compile_options`. Here is an example which applies the c++17 standard for a defined executable:

```
set_property(TARGET my_executable PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
set_property(TARGET my_executable PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2020-01-09**:
@gvdhoorn Alright, thanks for your help!

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2020-01-09**:
@pavel92 Great hint, thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-09**:
I would use `target_compile_features(..)` with a meta-feature instead, but it depends on your CMake version whether that is available.

**Comment by [audrius](https://answers.ros.org/users/36573/audrius/) on 2021-05-23**:
We do not have any issues with linking our C++17 code to noetic. Everything builds and runs just fine, with all tests passing.

**Comment by [allsey87](https://answers.ros.org/users/92272/allsey87/) on 2022-05-25**:
It depends a bit on the compilers in use. For example, if you use one version of GCC to build everything then you are fine to link C++11, 14, and 17 code together (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119902/5164339)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well it certainly breaks with C++20, both ROS Melodic and Noetic. Just beware.

---

Originally posted by [vilas](https://answers.ros.org/users/55638/vilas/) with karma: 21 on 2020-06-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2